# Slide view together with UICollectionView cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

i have this structure. Scrollview -> UICollectionview + Label

This viewcontroller has array of items (BlockItem). On scrollViewDidScroll i change current test label (description)

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView:UIScrollView)
{
    let midX:CGFloat = scrollView.bounds.midX
    let midY:CGFloat = scrollView.bounds.midY
    let point:CGPoint = CGPoint(x:midX, y:midY)
    guard

        let indexPath:IndexPath = collectionView.indexPathForItem(at:point)

        else
    {
        return
    }

    let currentPage:Int = indexPath.item
    if let found = items.first(where: {$0.id == String(block[currentPage])}) {
        description.text = found.description
    }

}
```

The main issue that i want my description label will be moving together when i move my collectionview cell and appear from the next cell. In other words, if I scroll to the left my description should move along with the cell, i.e. go to the left and appear on the right of the screen.

How can i do this? I know i could make a big collectionview but i need that only image part should be scrollable, not the entire block.

[image]

Here is what i want to achieve

[image]

Here is video example: scroll works only if i swipe on the image area, and doesn't work when i scroll down the page
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kl1GYgXvK4bL3toTfOvpxF2WqS56pQO9/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You can add that label as header or footer view. Collection view is inherited from scrollview., So you no need them separately most of the time.

Comment: But seems like header or footer will be also static? (they won't moving along with the cell)

Comment: I've updated my question with the picture

Answer (score 0):

You exactly said this:

"The main issue that I want my description label will be moving together when I move my collection view cell and appear from the next cell."

If you want your description label moving together, just include them into your collection cell. It's very clear from your point there

I don't understand why u need to separate it, but you want it to slide from new cell.

If you insisted that you want to archive the label, not in a scroll view, then use 2 label

One label for this cell and one label will come from scroll direction, u can archive this by creating manually. This is a simple code for a swipe left to scroll

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
   //insert your label animation 
   //current label moved with the scroll to left
   //create a new label from the outer right of the current view, scroll it to the middle of your view
}
```

But it will be hard work for good animation or scroll support.

Comment: But i don't want to scroll entire cell when i swipe on description block, scroll should works only if i swipe on Image. So if i include my description to cell it won't work like this

Comment: @user3296088 then you can use my suggestion with that code

Comment: i've added a video example to my link. could you check it? maybe I didn't make it clear